# Why doesn't it work? Trying to add row with hidden submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a simple Todo List with the enter button as a submit. This will add what was typed to the list below it. I feel like I'm missing something because its not working for me. My button is hidden to try to make the page cleaner. Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#hiddenEnterBtn").on("click", function() {

   var newTodo, newRow, newTd;

   newTodo = $("#inputField").val();
   newRow = $("<tr>");
   newTd = $("<td>").addclass("undone").append(newTodo);
   newRow.append(newTd);

   $("tbody").append(newRow);

 });
});

   <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <th>Things that should get done...like yeah get on that</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <form>
              <input type="text" id="inputField" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="What I need to do" />
              <button type="submit" id="hiddenEnterBtn"></button>
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: When you say it's hidden, is it still clickable?

Comment: Define "not working".  What *specifically* is failing?

Comment: How do you click on a hidden button?

Comment: When I type type in the input field and type enter nothing happens. Nothing is added. The button is hidden with display:none; in css. Even without having the button hidden and clicking on it manually it still does not add the row. :/

Comment: How does hitting enter click a hidden button?

Comment: $("#hiddenEnterBtn").on("click", function() {    is an event listener for the id that corresponds to button. It is waiting for the click event. Now even when I unhide the button and press it as my input it still does not add the row :/

Comment: The `<form>` is still behaving as normal, which involves navigating to the `action` (the current address if one isn't given). This will effectively reload the page, discarding any modifications the script may have accomplished. You'll want to use [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) on the `<form>`'s [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event to disable this.

Comment: A million thank you's @JonathanLonowski!! That was what I was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You neen to add `event.preventDefault()` in the begin of the click event to prevent to be sent. So your code should be:

```
$("#hiddenEnterBtn").on("click", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

   var newTodo, newRow, newTd;

   newTodo = $("#inputField").val();
   newRow = $("<tr>");
   newTd = $("<td>").addclass("undone").append(newTodo);
   newRow.append(newTd);

   $("tbody").append(newRow);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As in this [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xn2da6xb/), you need to prevent the default behavior of the submit button first, then perform your work as you want

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".table form").on("submit", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

   var newTodo, newHtml;

   newTodo = $("#inputField").val();
   newHtml = '<tr><td class="undone">' + newTodo + '</td></tr>';

   $("tbody").append(newHtml);

 });
});
```

```css
#hiddenEnterBtn{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
      <thead>
        <th>Things that should get done...like yeah get on that</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <form>
              <input type="text" id="inputField" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="What I need to do" />
              <button type="submit" id="hiddenEnterBtn"></button>
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working JS fiddle for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/0267stfq/1/

```
    <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <th>Things that should get done...like yeah get on that</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form method="POST" onsubmit="return false;">
          <input type="text"mautocomplete="off" placeholder="What I need to do" />
          <button></button>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("button").on("click", function() {
     var newTodo = $("input").val();
     $('.table tbody tr:last').after('<tr> <td>' + newTodo + '</td> </tr>');
 });
});
```